# Setting up Reverse DNS Records

Tags: email, dns, email-spam

This question is not directly programming related but I need my Server to pass Spam filters for my app to work properly. I talked to my ISP about rDNS and the guy from tech-support told me if I write an email with what they should add to my DNS record they would do that. My question:

What should I tell him to add if my hostname is "http://niklasfi.de" and my is 78.31.67.216?

Thanks für the answers. I tried searching on the Web but i only very specific anwers concerning a single ISP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reverse DNS is simply a record where the lookup is to find your host name from your IP address. So you should ask him to add a reverse IN-ADDR entry for 78.31.67.216 with your hostname.

this would be: 216.67.31.78.in-addr.arpa  niklasfi.de

These are also known as PTR records.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify. http://niklasfi.de is not a host name. It's a URI or URL. A host name would be mail.niklausfi.de for example.

I looked it up using one of the many service on the web (search for "reverse DNS lookup"). The mentioned IP address has already an IN-ADDR record. It's 216-67-31-78-rb1.sit.dsl.dynamic.acsalaska.net.