# How can I set up reverse DNS on my Ruby on Rails website?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reverse-dns

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide with this issue!

For my website, users are supposed to receive an activation email after registering. Some emails are not being received, and they're not going to spam filter folders, either.

After reviewing my integral_mailer log, I think I've uncovered the problem. Systems seem to be rejecting the messages because there is no reverse DNS information.

- Here is what Comcast had to say in reply to a rejected message: http://postmaster.comcast.net/smtp-error-codes.php#554)
- Here is what AOL had to say: http://postmaster.aol.com/Postmaster.Errors.php#421dnsnr
- I checked this article but couldn't set up my own reverse DNS: [Setting up Reverse DNS Records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621601/setting-up-reverse-dns-records)

I'm somewhat of a novice with RoR. Can you guide me in setting up the required reverse DNS information for my mailer?

As background, here are details from user_mailer.rb:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
def signup_notification(user)
setup_email(user)
@subject    += 'Please activate your new account'
@body[:url]  = "http://website.com/activate/#{user.activation_code}"
end
```

From integral_mailer.rb:

```
module IntegralMailer
def perform_delivery_integral_mailer(mail)
destinations = mail.destinations
mail.ready_to_send

helo = smtp_settings[:helo] || "localhost.localdomain"

ActionMailer::Base::INTEGRAL_MAILER_SERVER.send_mail(helo, mail.from, destinations, mail.encoded)
end
end
```

Comment: How are you hosting this site? Shared hosting provider, dedicated hosting provider, or on your own machine at home?

Comment: The DNS stuff has nothing at all to do with RoR.  Contact your web hosting provider for DNS help.

Comment: Thanks, guys. I really appreciate your responses. I was on the phone with the domain host for a half-hour before being directed to the web host, Joyent. Then, I found this article [http://am1-wiki.joyent.us/display/smart/Host+Names,+IP+Addresses,+Zone+Names,+and+Reverse+Records] I sent in a support request as required for establishing the reverse DNS. Will let you know the results! FYI, the link I shared keeps adding a final bracket to the URL.

Comment: After Joyent set up the reverse DNS as described above, emails were accepted by AOL and Comcast. Again, thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The website is hosted on Joyent, though the domain is through Go Daddy. Go Daddy does not do reverse DNS (even if the website is hosted through it.) The solution was to contact Joyent and to request that it set up the reverse DNS.

http://wiki.joyent.com/wiki/display/gen/DNS+Guide explains how to set up the reverse DNS through Joyent.

After a day or two, AOL, Comcast, and others started accepting emails from the website.

Comment: That page has likely changed since this answer.  There is no mention of "reverse DNS" there now.  I was able to solve this with a direct support inquiry to Joyent.