# How should a PTR DNS record look like when using default Azure server for reverse DNS?

Tags: azure, dns, reverse-dns

I'm trying to add a PTR record (reverse DNS) in Azure, but I'm not sure what should be the value in the PTR DNS record, My azure settings are:

> DNS NAME people-dns.cloudapp.net
>
> HOST NAME people-dns
>
> PUBLIC VIRTUAL IP (VIP) ADDRESS 137.117.11.18
>
> INTERNAL IP ADDRESS 100.68.96.97

The DNS name points to the mail server...

I understand that I don't need to run any PowerShell commands if I'm using the default DNS name (but maybe I'm wrong?)

I was simply adding a PTR record (using Google Domains) with value people-dns.cloudapp.net for the domain, but I don't know if I need to specify some IP addresses or type it reversed like I saw in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621601/setting-up-reverse-dns-records)

[image]

I found out that the PTR record is critical to avoid email rejections from GMail as I'm trying to resolve a problem where email ends up as SPAM for GMail users when they get it for the first time...

**Do you think I should add or change anything?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, my DNS PTR entry on Google Domains was correct (it has to include "." at the end)

The command I used to add a reverse DNS on Azure looks like this:

> **Set-AzureService** -ServiceName "people-dns" -Description "people-dns reverse DNS" -ReverseDnsFqdn "people-dns.cloudapp.net."

You can also use **Get-AzureService** to set the name to be used and confirm the service status

Also, there are web sites such as [mxtoolbox.com](http://mxtoolbox.com) that can check if the PTR record is valid, you can also check it manually - see my other question: [How to verify that Azure Reverse DNS is working properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34561460/how-to-verify-that-azure-reverse-dns-is-working-properly)

Answer (score 4):

The thing to remember about PTRs is that they're a *reverse* lookup.  The name of the record represents your IP address and the value contains your DNS name.

As a result, they don't live in the DNS zone that maps to that DNS name at all!  They live in separate, special zones called 'ARPA' zones (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup) to learn more).  These zones are owned by the organization owning the IP block you are using - in this case, Microsoft.

Microsoft Azure provides the ability to specify the PTR record associated with the IP address assigned to your service ([here's how](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/announcing-reverse-dns-for-azure-cloud-services/)).  Since this resides in the Microsoft-owned ARPA zone, you do this completely separate from your normal DNS zone management.

Regards,

Jonathan Tuliani, Program Manager, Azure Networking - DNS and Traffic Manager