# How to verify that Azure Reverse DNS is working properly?

Tags: azure, dns, azure-powershell, reverse-dns

I just got a static IP and ran the command below to get a reserved DNS:

> **Set-AzureService** -ServiceName "people-dns" -Description "people-dns
>   reverse DNS" -ReverseDnsFqdn "people-dns.cloudapp.net."

Now if I run **Get-AzureService** it shows:

> ReverseDnsFqdn          : people-dns.cloudapp.net.

**How can I verify that it is working properly?**

(it would be nice to automate this test so I can know if it stops working too)

UPDATE : I found web sites that can check like http://mxtoolbox.com but I like to know how they do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows you can use ping or nslookup in command line. w.x.y.z is ip of your service.

For **ping**:

```
ping -a w.x.y.z
```

For **nslookup**:

```
nslookup
set type=PTR
w.x.y.z
```

For automation use powershell with this command:

```
[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry("w.x.y.z")
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most reliable way of automating this would be to write a script to run on a schedule in Azure Automation that first queries `Get-AzureService` for the IP Address, and then checks the reverse PTR (using the command from @Łukasz Kałużny)

`[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry("w.x.y.z")`

If these don't match you can configure it to email or pull a webhook etc to inform you.